Updating react native and getting Subclasses must implement a valid getBundleURL method
I've recently updated react native to the latest version (as painful as it is), and I'm getting this error. The code compiles fine but as soon as the app runs I receive this.
'RCTAppDelegate::bundleURL not implemented', reason: 'Subclasses must implement a valid getBundleURL method'

Any ideas? Thanks!

Is it an expo app? Is it a prebuild app? Does this error occur on iOS or Android ?

@MichaelBahl expo app running iOS

Do you have a native iOS folder ?

@MichaelBahl yes

That means you ran npx expo prebuild or you eject your project.
Check your ios/[your app name]/AppDelegate.m file and post what ist the parameter for jsBundleURLForBundleRoot.

@MichaelBahl it is:
jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@".expo/.virtual-metro-entry"];

Did you try to build the app within Xcode?
Does your pod file contain the target ?
Do you have an Apple Silicon Mac or an Intel?

I've been through this as well and solved this issue by dividing the sourceURLForBridge method inside the AppDelegate.m into two functions:
If you're using expo it should be:
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self bundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)bundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@".expo/.virtual-metro-entry"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

If you're using plain cli it should be:
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self bundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)bundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

This is also how you're AppDelegate looks like, if you create a plain new project - which is always a good reference after updating an old one.
